# How to detect when font-family of an element changes

Tags: jquery, html

Using JQuery, is there a way to raise an event once the font-family of an HTML element changes?

Comment: Not natively. If you can change the font family, why not 'detect' the change when you call the function to change the font in the first place?

Comment: On what events do you anticipate the `font-fanily` changing?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var fontf= $('div').css('font-family');
myfunc(); 
function myfunc(){
 if(fontf != $('div').css('font-family'))
    alert('changed');
 else setTimeout(myfunc,1000);
}
```

Comment: `font-family` is not a valid variable name.